# Copy files from asset to SD card

Tags: android, android-assets

I'm new in developing Android app. Regarding my question, I've found the following post, but I'm not sure how to implement it to my existing project. 
[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)

I would like to implement it to ZhuangDict, a dictionary app capable of reading Stardict file.
http://code.google.com/p/zhuang-dict/source/browse/trunk/ZhuangDict/src/cn/wangdazhuang/zdict/ZhuangDictActivity.java

ZhuanDict creates an empty directory called "zdict" on first start.
What I wish to do is to copy my own stardict files from asset to zdict directory.

I have zero knowledge in programming. I would appreciate if you can provide me a step by step guide looking at the ZhuangDict source code from Google code.

Comment: This site is targeted at programmers, who encounter specific problems. If you have zero knowledge in programming, perhaps find a programmer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.packagename.myapp/databases/";

   try {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(
                "dbname.sqlite");
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[myInput.available()];
        int read;
        while ((read = myInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "copyDataBase Error : " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new in developing Android app without prior programming knowledge. Where should I put this code? In ZhuangDictActivity.java? Should I put it under which line?

Comment: You can place it anywhere when you want to copy the content.Place it in onCreate method for a try

Comment: I'm sorry. I need a step by step guide. I have zero knowledge in programming. Can you look at the ZhuangDict source code from Google code and guide me?

Comment: Place it after line number 303 in your code

Comment: I do not understand since your code mentioned about database. I do not intend to copy database. I just want to copy stardict .dict, .ifo and .idx files (there are 3 files) to sdcard/zdict/

Comment: Thank you. The answer you provided may work, but I don't have enough knowledge to do it myself. Probably I'll learn the complete android development starting from the basic in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put your file in the raw resource (/res/raw) folder and use this standard function:

```
protected void CopyResource(int aInputIDResource, String aOutputFileName, boolean afForceWrite) {
        if (afForceWrite == false) {
            InputStream theTestExist;
            try {
                theTestExist = openFileInput(aOutputFileName);
                theTestExist.close();
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        char[] theBuffer = new char[1024];
        int theLength;

        try {
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
                    aOutputFileName, MODE_WORLD_READABLE), "ISO-8859-1");
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(getResources()
                    .openRawResource(aInputIDResource), "ISO-8859-1");

            while ((theLength = in.read(theBuffer)) > 0)
                out.write(theBuffer, 0, theLength);

            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Then in the function onCreate() of your application or activity, call:

```
CopyResource(R.raw.your_database, "MR_SBusPlugin.so", false);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I need a step by step guide since I have zero knowledge in programming. Can you tell me where I should place the code in ZhuangDictActivity.java?